# Super Secret Settings

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the new snapshot of minecraft (13w36b) there is a super secret setting in the options menu. when hitting the button an enderman-ish sounds play. Does it do anything or is it just a sound?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `13w36b` all it does is play mysterious sounds, however a new menu is expected in future snapshots.

In `13w38a` clicking the button cycles between a number of shaders:

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are many more besides these three.

Comment: any idea what that menu will contain?

Comment: @RustyMembers No.

Comment: Yes. The only thing that has been said is that it's a new "community feature".

Comment: As of 1.8, there are about 18 different shaders included.

Comment: It would be nice to add that some of those effects result in sever framerate drop. I still hope to see the more non-resource-intensive ones (blurry vision, upside-down, hallucination etc.) as some in-game effects with purpose (being poisoned -> blurry vision + green color on the screen; make mushrooms edible and if eaten not as part of a stew add the hallucination effect; potion that inverts the world for whoever has drunk it or was hit by one etc.)

Answer (score -3):

It plays sounds that have been changed just like the `/playsound` command.